# getting mvc on shared host to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting

Any idea on how to get my asp.net mvc website to work on a webhost that's running asp.net 3.5 but maybe not IIS 7? (I think they might be on IIS 6)

I am on Crystal Tech and my home page shows up just fine but all other requests give me a 404 page not found error.

Note: I already follow these instructions but it's still not working

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

I had the same problem - I tried to fix it, but decided that spending the time screwing around with running on a backlevel server wasn't worth it.  In the end it was just easier for me to move to a host that ran Windows Server 2008 and IIS7.

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, which hosting provider did you go with?

Comment: i think i'll save myself the trouble and go with a new host. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have IIS7, then you may have an option to switch IIS7 between integrated and pipeline mode. Try switching to the other mode in your control panel. That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding an .aspx  at the end of all my routes in the route table("/{Controller}/{Action}/{id}.aspx").
You can add any extension that asp.net handles(like .mspx, .ashx, ...)
The only way to fix it without adding any extension is to ask your host to do so, or change your host to another with IIS7